# FusionAuth sendSetPasswordEmail not sending Set Password Email when creating a user

Tags: fusionauth

I'm wanting to create a user without specifying the password and have FusionAuth send the Setup Password email. I'm using the PHP client library, and while I can create a user the email is not been sent. However manually dispatching a Reset Password email is delivered successfully.

I've configured the SMTP settings to use my Mailgun account.

Here's what I'm sending via the client;

```
$this->authClient->createUser(null, [
        'user' => [
            'active'               => true,
            'sendSetPasswordEmail' => true,
            'birthDate'            => '01/01/1990',
            'email'                => 'a.valid@email.co.uk',
            'firstName'            => 'John',
            'fullName'             => 'John Doe',
            'lastName'             => 'Doe',
            'middleName'           => '',
            'mobilePhone'          => +447777777777,
            'password'             => 'ForSomeReasonThisNEEDStoBeSet',
            'data'                 => [
                'identifier' => $someIdentifier
            ],
            'memberships'          => [
                ['groupId' => $myGroupId]
            ],
            'preferredLanguages'   => ['en'],
            'timezone'             => 'Europe/London',
            'twoFactorEnabled'     => false,
            'usernameStatus'       => 'ACTIVE',
            'username'             => $username,
            'verified'             => true
        ]
    ]);
```

Even when I'm passing the `sendSetPasswordEmail` the `password` field is still required, however the docs suggest this shouldn't be the case;

> This field is optional only if sendSetPasswordEmail is set to true. By default sendSetPasswordEmail is false, and then this field will be required.

How can I get the Password Setup email to be send when creating a user? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the Event Logs to see if there are any template rendering or SMTP errors there? It could be a FreeMarker issue. Also, did you confirm that the Setup Password Template was correctly selected under the Tenant configuration on the Email tab? If all of those items look good, this could be a regression and you can open a GitHub issue for it.

Comment: @BrianPontarelli Both Event Logs are empty and the Tenant configuration has the correct template selected. I'll open a GitHub issue, thanks

Comment: @jakehallas answered your GitHub issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sendSetPasswordEmail` is a top level value in the JSON request. You need to move it up as a sibling to the `user` object.

Example:

```
$this->authClient->createUser(null, [
        'sendSetPasswordEmail' => true,
        'user' => [
            'active'               => true,
            'birthDate'            => '01/01/1990',
            'email'                => 'a.valid@email.co.uk',
            'firstName'            => 'John',
            'fullName'             => 'John Doe',
            'lastName'             => 'Doe',
            'middleName'           => '',
            'mobilePhone'          => +447777777777,
            'password'             => 'ForSomeReasonThisNEEDStoBeSet',
            'data'                 => [
                'identifier' => $someIdentifier
            ],
            'memberships'          => [
                ['groupId' => $myGroupId]
            ],
            'preferredLanguages'   => ['en'],
            'timezone'             => 'Europe/London',
            'twoFactorEnabled'     => false,
            'usernameStatus'       => 'ACTIVE',
            'username'             => $username,
            'verified'             => true
        ]
    ]);
```

Reference [Create User API](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/users#create-a-user)

Comment: Good catch. Missed that it was nested.